# Update a pointer in a set to point to an equivalent object with different properties in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, set

If I have a set of pointers `set<A*, comp> as` , when I insert a pointer `as.insert(p)`, that points to an equivalent object but with different properties, how can I use the iterator returned by insert() to update the pointer to point to the new object?

object a1 has name "a" and size 5

object a2 has name "a" and size 10

object a3 has name "a" and size 25

The set is ordered by the name of the object.

```
as.insert(&a1);
as.insert(&a2);
as.insert(&a3);
```

I would like that the pointer in the set to point to last inserted object, a3, with size 25.

Thanks

Comment: I've seen code that does this and it's terrible and confusing to everyone.  If you're going to contain things in a set then the comparator must create identity--meaning that as for as anyone is concerned anything that the comparator calls equal is identical in the scope of that set and its clients.  @RSahu gives the right answer, but don't do it.  The easiest alternative would be to make a key object that has the subset of information necessary to implement the comparator and use them as keys to a map that contains the pointers to the true object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change what the pointer in the `set` points to. Allowing that would break the implicit ordering present in a `set`.

You'll need to remove the old pointer and insert the new pointer.

```
auto found = as.find(&a3);
if ( found != as.end() )
{
   as.erase(found);
}

as.insert(&a3);
```